# I can change color when I try clicking from red to purple, but jQuery doesn't seem to changing color when start from purple to red buttons

Tags: html, jquery, css

[Code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JX2ax.png)

I can change color when I try clicking from red to purple, but jQuery doesn't seem to changing color when I click from purple to red buttons. Please help.

body { font-weight: 400; } .red { color: red; } .green { color: green; } .yellow { color: yellow; } .purple { color: purple;

This is a heading!

```
<!-- <a href="http://jquery.com">jQuery</a> -->
<button id="red">Red</button>
<button id="green">Green</button>
<button id="yellow">Yellow</button>
<button id="purple">Purple</button>

<script>
     $("#red").click(function () {
     $("#heading1").addClass("red");
  });

  $("#green").click(function () {
    $("#heading1").addClass("green");
  });

  $("#yellow").click(function () {
    $("#heading1").addClass("yellow");
  });

  $("#purple").click(function () {
    $("#heading1").addClass("purple");
  });
```

Comment: it is because you didn't remove old class that already added when you click other button. and also, if you want to check why it doesn't work, you can [open devtools](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/open/). then you can see what's changing and what's wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you can try as shared. Usage of removeClass would do

```
    <head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style>
body { font-weight: 400; } .red { color: red; } .green { color: green; } .yellow { color: yellow; } .purple { color: purple;


</style>

<h1 id="heading1">This is a Heading</h1>

<!-- <a href="http://jquery.com">jQuery</a> -->
<button id="red">Red</button>
<button id="green">Green</button>
<button id="yellow">Yellow</button>
<button id="purple">Purple</button>

<script>
    $("#red").click(function () {
        $("#heading1").removeClass();
        $("#heading1").addClass("red");
    });

  $("#green").click(function () {
      $("#heading1").removeClass();
    $("#heading1").addClass("green");
  });

  $("#yellow").click(function () {
      $("#heading1").removeClass();
    $("#heading1").addClass("yellow");
  });

  $("#purple").click(function () {
      $("#heading1").removeClass();
    $("#heading1").addClass("purple");
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

if you want to change background color you have to use: `background-color: red;`